# Get AWS API gateway host name in another independent lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API gateway using serverless deploy. AWS creates the url for the gateway dynamically, which looks like-

https://xxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/hello

Here **xxxx** (i.e. host) is being generated dynamically.

Please let me know is there any way to set this host manually(without creating custom domain and all that long process). 
OR
Is there any way to get this host name in another independent lambda using code.
We don't want to write hardcoded hostname in that lambda.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom domain is exactly the way to achieve this. You cannot set the id as it is autogenerated by API Gateway. So the long process you are talking about is unavoidable. It's not that long if you own a domain. You need to create a CNAME record for the custom domain to point to the one generated by API gateway, get and use free certificate from AWS Certificate Manager and set the API base mappings. The exact steps are given [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).

If you want to get this `id` programmatically, you can use the [getRestAPIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#getRestApis-property) method from node `aws-sdk` to get a list of your rest apis with their ids.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I found the same solution(using getRestAPIs). And this works really well.